# What is the best easy way to test Kafka broker/topics on the remote server by console?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, apache-kafka

Let me explain my scenario. I have an Asp.NetCore application hosted on the B machine. This application is responsible to produce messages to the topic in the broker which hosted on an A machine. But it can't produce any message to the topic and that's why I want to test through the console. I don't want to install too many applications on the B machine. So I'm looking up an effective and easy way to test the broker hosted in the A machine. It could be some authentication and authorization problem on the connection. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: try with kafka-producer on machine A .

Comment: Of course, I can do it. It's not a problem. I want to test the Kafka connection between A machine and B machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied a solution and It can be useful for you all;

I had the Python on the B machine. Because of that, I choose to solve it with python.

It is the build.sh;

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change current directory to project directory.
cd "$(dirname "$0")" || exit

# Install python3-venv package if not installed.
sudo apt install python3-venv

# Create virtual environment directory
python3 -m venv "venv/"

# Activate virtual environment
source "venv/bin/activate"

echo "[INFO] USING PYTHON:" "$(which python)"
echo "[INFO] USING PIP:" "$(which pip)"

# Upgrade Python
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Check the version of pip
# Version must be below 18.XX and compatible with Python 3.4+
pip --version

# Install dependencies
pip install  kafka-python==2.0.0
```

Tha main.py for the Kafka Consumer test;

```
from kafka import TopicPartition
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from datetime import datetime
import time, threading
import sys

print("Initialize")
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='yourbootstrapservers')
consumer.subscribe(['topicName'])
print('start for consuming')
for msg in consumer:
    print(msg)

print(next(consumer))
print("ended")
```

Firstly you need to execute build.sh and then execute the main.py for consuming. If everything will going on without any problem you will see some data.